# Nginx double slash after domain rewrite

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, nginx, url-rewriting

i'm using Nginx on production env, we have some url with double slash in uri, like this:

```
http://foo.com//bar/foo
```

i want to rewrite or redirect to:

```
http://foo.com/bar/foo
```

the option " merge_slashes " it's already enabled, and i have tried this:

```
merge_slashes off;
rewrite (.*)//+(.*) $1/$2 permanent;
```

but doesn't works, have you any idea?

thanks

EDIT:

so, the rewrite work if the slash is after the first "/" , i.e:

```
http://pippo.it/foo//bar
```

but if the double slash it's after the domain doesn't work, i.e:

```
http://pippo.it//foo/bar
```

i have tried to dump the variable $request_uri and this is the result:

```
url: http://pippo.it//foo/bar
expect: $request_uri -> //foo/bar
result: $request_uri -> /foo/bar

url: http://pippo.it///foo/bar
expect: $request_uri -> ///foo/bar
result: $request_uri -> //foo/bar
```

can be a bug?

EDIT 2:

i have found the error, the problem is the elb (aws), if i call directly the ec2 instance (where nginx it's installed) i can see the first 2 slashes, but if i call the elb, the load balancer delete the first slash, i have opened a case on the support center.

EDIT 3:

found the issue: if you set the elb with HTTP listener, i dont know why but the request doesn't have all slashes, if you set the listener in TCP mode, the request works fine.

Thanks

Comment: did you chage elb protocol or instance protocol?

Answer (score 3):

Setup is actually correct. Tested it with nginx/1.9.12

```
root@8317e542a878:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# curl -I localhost//              
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.9.12
Date: Mon, 18 Jul 2016 20:34:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Location: http://localhost/
Connection: keep-alive
```

Have you reloaded settings on running nginx?

```
nginx -s reload
```

Comment: i dont know why, but i have nginx/1.10 but doesn't work:

` MillenniumFalcon-2:Desktop Gianmarco$ curl -I https://pippo.com//it/milano/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: max-age=3660, public, s-maxage=600
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 13:46:15 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.0
Set-Cookie: 
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Language
Vary: Origin
Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: Let's see full nginx config? maybe some other directives brake logic.

Comment: this is the configuration:
`listen 80 default_server;
server_name pippo.it;
root /var/www/pippo.it/current/web;
location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
     }
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI $request_url;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$
fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
fastcgi_buffering off;
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
echo 'http://foo.com//bar/fool' | sed 's/\/\//\//g'
```

This is using the [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) unix command to search for `//` and replace them with `/`.

Comment: your expression doesn't work, the correct syntax it's this sed 's/\/\//\//g'